# How to get Turabian citation style in LaTex

Tags: bibtex

I am writing my thesis and I am using a Turabian style for figures and tables and i would like to be consistent and use the Turabian style for my citation also. I am using a bibtex for my citation. I am wondering if there exist a specific method to change the references into a Turabian style. Thanks

Comment: Turabian seems to be author-year based. There is a style based on this, but it relies on biblatex. Please check under "historian" http://biblatex.dominik-wassenhoven.de/author-year.shtml?en.

Comment: This looks pretty starightforward to produce with BibLaTeX with only minimal chnages to the base style.

Answer (score 4):

### Method 1: Using `biblatex-chicago` alone

For Turabian-style citations, consider using the [`biblatex-chicago`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago) package. It supports both the Notes-Bibliography and the Author-Date citation styles.

Specific to Notes-Bibliography, use:

```
\usepackage[notes, isbn=false]{biblatex-chicago}
```

In formatting the Bibliography/References when using the `\printbibliography` command (as part of the [`biblatex-chicago`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago) package), the following will also make adjustments based on the recommendations outlined in Turabian's manual:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\singlespacing}
\renewcommand{\bibitemsep}{1\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\bibhang}{0.5in}
```

### Method 2: Using `turabian-formatting` with `biblatex-chicago`

Use the [`turabian-formatting`](http://ctan.org/pkg/turabian-formatting) package. It provides the necessary formatting to produce a thesis according to Turabian's *A Manual for Writers of Research Papers, Theses, and Dissertations* (8th Edition). It also provides support for the [`biblatex-chicago`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago) package.

The following is an example of using the package's included `turabian-thesis` document class:

```
\documentclass{turabian-thesis}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes, ellipsis}

\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{my_bibliography.bib} % Your bibliography file

\title{The Title of Your Work}
\author{Your Name}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    The content of your paper.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This second method also provides Turban-style formatting, specific to a thesis, for the entire document.

Comment: The Chicago Manual *does* require footnote numbers to be non-superscript, and the `biblatex-chicago` package does this automatically, without footmisc.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, for the response. Edits made to the original post to correct this error.